# How to track down "Could not load type" error message

Tags: .net, silverlight-5.0

I'm trying to upgrade a .NET solution from SL3 to SL5, as well as upgrade to .NET 4

I have an issue with upgrading System.Windows.Interactivity.dll

The SL3 version is 1.0.1327.0
The SL5 version is 2.1.20402.0

After replacing the DLL, and removing the old service reference then adding the new one, the IDE gives me the following message

```
Could not load type 'System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingPanel' from assembly 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'.
```

I can't figure out why the application is trying to reference the 2.0.50 version System.Windows (indeed the reference is 5.0.5.0).  I'm completely stuck at the moment and have no idea how to track down the problem.

Comment: Does it give the source assembly, or is that the full text of the error message record?

Comment: The full error from the IDE is "Error 24 Could not load type 'System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingPanel' from assembly 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'. M:\XXX\OverallResults\App.xaml 1 1 OverallResults (SilverlightPlugins\OverallResults)
"

Comment: Unload each of your projects, and search the `.proj` XML for references to the 2.0.5.0 version of the DLL.

Comment: I used grep to search every .vbproj file for 2.0.5.0 and found nothing.  Matter of fact "2.0.5.0" doesn't exist in ANY file

Comment: The project file might not contain the version in clear text, but it might contain a `<HintPath>` node. Anyway I'd suggest trying Tony318's answer below, it worked for me, although it's quite tedious.

Comment: The hint path is there.  I've experimented with just overwriting the DLL  for both 2.0.50 and 5.0.5.0 and changing nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Remove and re-add all of your references making sure they are all the correct version. Also, double check your project app pool and make sure they are compatible with the .dll's Thats a good place to start.

Comment: For those downvoting. If you could specify in the comments why it is downvoted that would be great.